# SourceTree shows endless graph

Tags: git, git-rebase, sourcetree

I rebased 6 branches from master and SourceTree shows me weird endless frpah.

[image: beginning]

...

[image: repo bottom]

As you can see, those stripes goes below enitial commit and i can't scroll down anymore.

At the same time Intellij idea shows graphas expected:

[image]

How can i know if i did something wrong or it is SourceTree bug?

Comment: It would be useful to provide real links between the commits which you are interested in. For example with `git show -s --pretty=format:%s:%h:%p <commit1>...<commitN>`. Also did you request for any filtering in the SourceTree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most reliable way is command line:

```
log --graph --decorate --oneline --all
```

Comment: This SoureTree view shows a tree of commits. What do you mean - `patches`?

Comment: I mean they were `rebased`, commits were re-created the similar way when you apply patches. There is another committer id and commit time.

Comment: If something was rebased, it mean another commit(s) was created and it definitely will be shown by `git log` command described below. So, this is a SourceTree bug

Comment: Yes, it is showm, but in case of SourceTree, such commits has endless lines on graph which scares me

Comment: I suggest to use command line or/and SmartGit (I like this tool) :-)